# What is the name of the new bad guys in Dr Who episode Deep Breath? (Season 8 Ep 1)

Tags: doctor-who

During the episode they were referred to as

> Repair droids

But I don't think they were ever called by their actual name. What are they called?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Those are the [Clockwork Droids](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Clockwork_Droid), previously seen in [The Girl in the Fireplace](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/The_Girl_in_the_Fireplace_(TV_story)).

Comment: Yep, from the sister ship of the ship in the previous episode.

Comment: The ship in Deep Breath is the 'SS Marie Antoinette', which is the sister ship of the 'SS Madame de Pompadour' from The Girl in the Fireplace.

Comment: +1 thanks. And I've also since found that the leader is known as Half Face Man.

Comment: See also: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/66534/1027